# don't work udf javascripts in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

- create keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
```

- in testkeyspace create function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION first_int(input set) RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS int LANGUAGE javascript AS '(function(){var result = 2;return result;})();';
```

- create table and insert:

```
create table A (id int primary key, val set);
insert into A  (id, val) values (1, {3,5,7,1});
```

- select:

```
select first_int(val) from A where id = 1;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1044, in perform_simple_statement
    result = future.result()
  File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.10.zip/cassandra-driver-3.10/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3826, in result
    raise self._final_exception
FunctionFailure: Error from server: code=1400 [User Defined Function failure] message="execution of 'testkeyspace.first_int[set]' failed: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied: ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.java.io")"
```

raw log:

```
root@001b19bd3cc6:/# cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.1 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
cqlsh> USE testkeyspace ;
cqlsh:testkeyspace> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION first_int(input set<int>) RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS int LANGUAGE javascript AS '(function(){var result = 2;return result;})();';
cqlsh:testkeyspace> create table A (id int primary key, val set<int>);
cqlsh:testkeyspace> insert into A  (id, val) values (1, {3,5,7,1});
cqlsh:testkeyspace> select first_int(val) from A where id = 1;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1044, in perform_simple_statement
    result = future.result()
  File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.10.zip/cassandra-driver-3.10/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3826, in result
    raise self._final_exception
FunctionFailure: Error from server: code=1400 [User Defined Function failure] message="execution of 'testkeyspace.first_int[set<int>]' failed: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied: ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.java.io")"
```

[cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) [cassandra-3.11.1](/questions/tagged/cassandra-3.11.1)

Comment: do you have `enable_user_defined_functions` & `enable_scripted_user_defined_functions` set to true in your `cassandra.yaml` file?

Comment: yes, enable_user_defined_functions and enable_scripted_user_defined_functions in true

Comment: it's interesting, it looks like JS-interpreter is trying to call one of the black-listed classes. This could be a bug in Cassandra that maybe makes sense to report to development team

Comment: bug reported https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14126

Comment: Please also add information about these 2 configuration parameters, etc.